# Create Angular Components Dynamically at Runtime

Tags: angular, components

I'm wanting to create Angular components at runtime.  The use case is that there are different reports, each being a component and inheriting from a base report component.

Based on the configuration in the DB, I want to load a component based on the name of the component class.  Not sure if this is possible or not?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Answer (score 0):

Components don't really exist in the runtime environment. That all get optimised away by webpack and minified during the build. Loading a component by name won't work if you are planning on running a prod build because the name won't exist, it will be randomly minified.

I would recommend instead setting up a series of routes that load the components you want depending on the db value returning from some api call.

```
/reports/a
/reports/b
```

Or alternatively you could make one route which contains an `ngSwitch` that loads the component you want.